# Run Servo when detect object on OpenCV Python

Tags: python, opencv, arduino, serial-port

I want to connect OpenCV (Python) with arduino Uno when it detects a tennis ball. In theory, when a tennis ball is detected, a servo should turn 180 degree via arduino. Tennis ball is detected from a live video feed.

OpenCV code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import serial
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('tennisballdetect.xml')
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while 1:
ret, img = cap.read()
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
print(faces)
for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 0, 0), 2)
detect=(x+y)/2
print(detect)
cv2.imshow('img', img)
k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
if k == 27:
break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# Module -2: Trigger Pyserial
if detect > 0:

 ser = serial.Serial('COM1', 9600)
 print(ser)
 ser.write('Y')
else:

ser = serial.Serial('COM1', 9600)
 print(ser)
 ser.write('N')
```

My Arduino Code:

```
 #include <Servo.h> 
int servoPin = 3;
Servo Servo1;
char incomingBit;    // for incoming serial data

void setup() {

Servo1.attach(servoPin);
pinMode(servoPin, OUTPUT);     
Serial.begin(9600);    
}
void loop() {
if (Serial.available() > 0) {       


incomingBit = Serial.read();
Serial.print("I received:  ");
Serial.print(incomingBit);

        if(incomingBit == 'Y' || incomingBit == 'y') {


  Servo1.write(0); 
  delay(1000); 

   Servo1.write(90); 
  delay(1000); 

   Servo1.write(180); 
  delay(1000); 
 //exit(0);
        }
        else {
          digitalWrite(servoPin, LOW); 
        }
   }
 }
```

Servo is correctly connected to Arduino and it is moving without serial communication. openCV is also working and detecting tennisball.

But when trying to connect OpenCV to arduino, servo is not moving. Also serial.print(incomingBit) command not giving any value. 
I think the problem is detect>0 continuously, and that is jamming serial connection somehow. So when tennis ball is detected, I just need to send 1 signal until the ball is out of frame. How can I do that?

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

COM1 is almost never the Arduino port. Double check that.

Also, try testing your Arduino sketch emulating a 'y' entry with Serial Monitor.

(Make sure you disable character termination on Serial Monitor)